# Fix fluorescent flickering from video using matlab

Tags: matlab, flicker

I have several video sequences exhibiting light intensity flickering (under fluorescent light sources).
This is due to the shutter speed and/or sampling rate not being a whole  multiple of the electrical frequency. For example - shooting video at 1/50 second shutter speeds with 60Hz electrical frequency.

In general - I need to solve this without knowing the sampling rate, electrical frequency, video frame rate. I just see the flickering and need to fix them.

The video scenes include moving objects as well (some move slow, some as fast as the rapid change in intensity due to the flickering).

Is there a well known method of dealing with such flickering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The common method for removing flickering is along the following lines. Looking at the difference image between consecutive frames, the flickering should appear as a strong periodic signal along the vertical axis of the image. Therefore, it should have a strong coefficient in the frequency domain. Thus, the flickering can be detected and removed by finding the coefficients in frequency domain that represent the flickering in the difference image, nullifying them and transforming back to space domain.

In pseudocode this algorithm looks like this:

```
imDiff = I_{t+1} - I_t (Compute the difference between subsequent video frames)
imDiff = FilterImDiff(imDiff)
imDiffRowSum = RowSum(imDiff) (summing the rows of the diff image)
dctCoef = DiscreteCosineTransform(imDiffRowSum)
flickeringDctCoef = SomeHeuristicToFindFlickeringCoef(dctCoef)
flickeringIm = CloneColumn(InverseDiscreteCosineTransform(fixedDctCoef), numCols)
fixedimDiff = imDiff - flickeringIm 
fixedI_{t+1} = I_{t+1} + fixedimDiff
```

where:

- RowSum(x) takes an m x n image as input and returns a column vector of size m x 1 where element i contains the sum of the i'th row in the image x.
- CloneColumn(x, n) takes a column vector x of size m and clones it n times in order to create an m x n matrix.
- numCols is the number of columns in the input image.
- a simple algorithm for SomeHeuristicToNullifyFlickeringCoef can be choosing the first couple of largest coefficients, if they are greater than a certain threshold.
- FilterImDiff should discard stuff from the difference image that doesn't contain flickering, such as movement of foreground objects. For example, pixels that have a temporal difference that is greater than the maximal magnitude of flickering. Also, pixels that are too bright or too dark usually don't have flickering in them.

Comment: Is your last line supposed to be "fixedI_{t+1} = I_{t} + fixedDiffImage" ?

Comment: I'll go over it later. Toda :)

Comment: I forgot to ask - you wrote 'the flickering should appear as a strong periodic signal along the vertical axis of the image'. I don't understand why this has to be. I don't have the movies in front of me but I think I saw examples with horizontal flickering and also diagonal varieties...

Comment: The flickering can be horizontal if the rolling shutter of the camera travels from left to right instead of top to bottom. Diagonals (or worse) may appear depending on the scene geometry.

Comment: It goes without saying that image flickering is the result of the rolling shutter's frequency being much faster than the fluorescenct's frequency. This effect, however, is hardly visible to the eye. Now, the problem with video is that the frame acquisition frequency may not be a multiple of the fluorescenct's frequency. It causes the flickering to appear in consecutive images in different phases, and this effect of phase change is visible to the eye.

Comment: Well... I must be missing something as I've wasted the better part of today trying to implement your suggestion and it doesn't work. If you'll kindly look at the attached code snippet I'll be ever grateful :) - here it is https://copy.com/i7w8xJMryuXXVKLv

Comment: One mistake is that you subtract the mean image instead of subtracting the previous image. Another mistake is that the you compute the fixed image incorrectly. See the pseudocode.

Comment: I subtracted the mean because every frame has those annoying white bars and to get rid of them my reference should be a similar frame with no bars. It's not in the code snippet I uploaded to copy, but I also tried subtracting the previous frame (for loop from frame 2-->8) and also tried Im{i}+imDiff-flickeringIm (the opposite signs of what you saw I did) and things are even worse that way...